# Creating Framework in corona

Tags: frameworks, lua, coronasdk

how to create a framework for a character in corona so that i can use it in different levels?
eg.I want to make a physics character so that I can use it in different levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create it as a separate Lua module so that you can `require("your_character")` in other code files (levels).

Comment: how to make "your_character" file.how to create objects and the use it in different file.

Comment: create "your_character.lua" file the same way you create any other file. For the actual check of how this file should look like, get a copy of a "movieclip" module and check in there.